# Highlight the particular text inside a datagridview cell in c#windows application

Tags: c#

Does anyone know how to highlight or change the color of the particular text inside a datagridview cell? Not change the back or fore colors of the all cells, but only for a particular word inside the cell.I tried doing it in the Cell_Formatting event of the datagridview but I'm only seeing options to change color of the entire cells.

my coding is:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RowColor();
}

private void RowColor()
{
    DataGridViewRow dgvr = dataGridView1.Rows[0];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["status"].Value)))
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["status"].Value != null)
        {
            dgvr.Cells["status"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for advice.

[my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrmfu.png)ck.imgur.com/3lKFa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you can change the background color:

```
dgvr.Cells["status"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Also, you can change the text color like this:

```
dgvr.Cells["status"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Therefore, you can change the cell background/text color in `CellFormatting` event handler like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "status" && e.Value is string)
    {
        string text = (string)e.Value;

        if (text == "PAUSE")
        {// Change the color
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I connect my datagridview in database the status column contain PAUSE,RINGING option. i need to change all the PAUSE cell as highlighted. help me please.

Comment: Couldn't you change the color of "PAUSE" cells in `CellFormatting` event handler?

Comment: it changes all the cells color of my datagridview.

Comment: @divya I've updated my answer to change the color for only "PAUSE" cells. Try that:)